# How to change an object by condition in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a static object that describes my "style":

```
 public static IconsStyle = {
       height: 51,
       justifyContent: 'center',
       background: 'inherit'
   };
```

I want to push "width : 60" field to my object if window.InnerWidth will be < 850px.

Comment: `if(window.InnerWidth < 850) IconsStyle.width = 60`?

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava Yes

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - if you have questions you know aren't appropriate, don't post them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.defineProperty(IconsStyle, 'width', {
                value: 60,
                writable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation!?

Comment: @WernerHenze I do agree, the answer should include any explanation on what exactly the code does and how it solves the problem. Anyhow I do believe, you can formulate this somewhat nicer. For some people this might be offending, even if just slightly.